# MySQL UNIQUE CONSTRAINT failing in CREATE TABLE with subsequent INSERT

Tags: mysql

Using phpMyAdmin and MySQL v5.5.49 consider:

```
CREATE TABLE op_sys (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    version VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    -- UNIQUE KEY name_version (name, version)
    -- CONSTRAINT name_version UNIQUE (name, version)
    -- UNIQUE(name, version)
    -- CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(name, version)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I've tried all four of the commented out attempts to simply stop INSERT INTO sys_op duplicate values for "name" and "version".  All four are processed without error.

The insert into:

```
INSERT INTO op_sys(name, version)
VALUES ('ANDROID','ANDROID');
```

executes "successfully".  ANDROID ANDROID is now a row.  Where have I gone wrong or what step am I not aware of?  I've checked the MySQL manual and several different posts here that seem to say I'm doing it correctly... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what [UNIQUE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) means:

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE
>   index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.

If your table has `UNIQUE(name, version)`, then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO op_sys(name, version) VALUES ('ANDROID','ANDROID');
```

But, the next time you do it, it will fail because the table already holds a record with the same pair(name, version) as in the record you want to insert.

To prevent inserting a record that has the same value for `name` and version`, you could use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER different_values BEFORE INSERT ON op_sys
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 DECLARE identical_values CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
 IF NEW.name = NEW.version THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Identical values for name and version';
 END IF;
END;
```

It will run before each `INSERT` on table `sys_op`, and if the `name` and `version` fields hold identical values, it will generate an error and the insertion will fail.

The error returned looks like this:

```
ERROR 1644 (45000): Identical values for name and version
```

Documentation:
- [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)
- [CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)
- [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

A multi-column unique index prevents you to have the same 2 values for these 2 fields **between records**. This means, you cannot have 2 records, where name and version are 'ANDROID','ANDROID'. However, a unique index does not prevent these fields from having the same value within a single row.

You either have to implement this control in application level, where you check if the 2 field values are the same and if yes, then do  not do the insertion.

In the database layer you could ad a before insert trigger and check the 2 fields' value there and raise a custom error message using the [signal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) command.

But I have such a de ja vu feeling. As if you had asked this question before and you could not do an if() in php...

Comment: No, first time.  Yes, easy on the php side - just check if the value is in the column prior to executing the insert.  I'll explore triggers, as this seems to be what I'm missing.  Thanks!